# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern Error

Tags: c#, linq

Given

```
   var selectedItems = listBoxControl1.SelectedItems;
   var selectedItemsList = (from i in selectedItems
                             select i).ToList();
```

I receive Error

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseListBoxControl.SelectedItemCollection'. 
>   'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the
>   range variable 'i'.

`using system.LINQ` Done

I can use foreach so it must implement `IEnumerable`.  I prefer to use LINQ over foreach to gather each string, if possible.

I want to take the `ToString()` values for each SelectedItem in the list box control and stick them in a `List<string>`.  How can I do it?

Comment: for a foreach to work the type of the object after the keyword in simply needs to have a mthod called GetEnumerator() which in turn returns an object of a type that has a MoveNext() method and a Current property. It does **not** need to implement IEnumerable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I can use foreach so it must implement IEnumerable.

That's not actually true, but it's irrelevant here. It *does* implement `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<T>` which is what LINQ works over.

What's actually *in* the list? If it's already strings, you could use:

```
var selectedItemsList = selectedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

Or if it's "any objects" and you want to call `ToString` you can use:

```
var selectedItemsList = selectedItems.Cast<object>()
                                     .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                     .ToList();
```

Note that the call to `Cast` is why the error message suggested using an explicitly typed range variable - a query expression starting with `from Foo foo in bar` will be converted to `bar.Cast<Foo>()...`

Comment: What is required to implement foreach?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: A method called `GetEnumerator()` which is declared to return a type with suitable `MoveNext()` and `Current` members. It doesn't have to implement `IEnumerable`. Using a type with a `Current` property of (say) `int` was a way to avoid boxing while iterating before generics.

Comment: just login to up cast this

Answer (score 7):

For LINQ to work, you need an `IEnumerable<T>`, straight IEnumerable isn't enough. Try:

```
var selectedItems = listboxControl1.SelectedItems.Cast<T> //where T is the actual type of the item
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just

```
var result = listBoxControl1.SelectedItems.Cast<MyItemType>().ToList();
```